# how to create the feature column in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

i am working on the feature_column construction following the tensorflow document, but i met some problem, can anyone help me? THX! this my code below:

#data is the dictionary of the train dataset

```
def demo(feature_column):
    feature_layer = layers.DenseFeatures(feature_column)
    return(feature_layer(data).numpy())
age = feature_column.numeric_column('Age')
age_bucket = feature_column.bucketized_column(age, boundaries = [30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])
age_fea = demo(age_bucket) #create age feature_column
gender = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('Gender', ['F', 'M'])
gender_one_hot = feature_column.indicator_column(gender) #create gender feature_column
smoking = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('Smoking', ['Y', 'N'])
smoking_one_hot = feature_column.indicator_column(smoking) #create smoking feature_column

#create the estimator
    model = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier( 
      n_classes = 2,
      model_dir = "ongoing/train6 ",
      feature_columns = [age_fea, gender_fea, icd9code_fea, smoking_fea]
    )
```

#train the estimator

```
  model.train( 
      input_fn = get_input_fn(csv_data, 5000, 10, True),
      steps = 1000
    )
```

and got an error listed below:

```
    (base) ous-MacBook-Pro:indiproject_copy congwang$ python try.py
2021-05-12 01:12:32.901336: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-05-12 01:12:32.901558: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py:63: The name tf.estimator.inputs is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From try.py:79: The name tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn instead.

WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/training_util.py:235: Variable.initialized_value (from tensorflow.python.ops.variables) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use Variable.read_value. Variables in 2.X are initialized automatically both in eager and graph (inside tf.defun) contexts.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/inputs/queues/feeding_queue_runner.py:60: QueueRunner.__init__ (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/inputs/queues/feeding_functions.py:491: add_queue_runner (from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
To construct input pipelines, use the `tf.data` module.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "try.py", line 106, in <module>
    model.train(
  File "/Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 349, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1175, in _train_model
    return self._train_model_default(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1203, in _train_model_default
    estimator_spec = self._call_model_fn(features, labels, ModeKeys.TRAIN,
  File "/Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 1163, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 982, in _model_fn
    return _linear_model_fn(
  File "/Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 744, in _linear_model_fn
    logits = logit_fn(features=features)
  File "/Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py", line 429, in linear_logit_fn
    linear_model = feature_column._LinearModel(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 639, in __init__
    self._feature_columns = _normalize_feature_columns(
  File "/Users/congwang/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py", line 2333, in _normalize_feature_columns
    raise ValueError('Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. '
ValueError: Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given (type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>): [[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 1. 0. 0.]].
```

the list in the valueError is the age_fea, when i delete the age_fea from estimator construction, the valueError lists the the list of gender_fea. as the demo returns an numpy ndarray rather than tensor, i am confused about what to feed into the feature_columns when constructing the model.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: in code you should use comments with `#` instead of  `///`

Comment: thanks for your help! i have already put the full error message in question, please have a look.

Comment: I can't run it so can only guess: in `demo()` you do `return .....numpy()` and this `.numpy()` can make problem

Comment: yes, so I am confused what I should feed into feature_column in the estimator construction step